# why can't $(this) be used in jquery .animate()?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have progress bar with bootstrap , this is html :

```js
$(".progress-bar").animate({
  width: $(this).data('width') + '%'
}, 2500);
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="alert alert-success">
  <div class="skill-name">ON PROGRESS 357/487</div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" data-width="70">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

why jquery on above not working if i used `$(this).data('width') + '%'` . But if i used `$(".progress-bar").data('width') + '%'` worked. ?thanks

**Edit**

If I use `$(".progress-bar").data('width') + '%'` It will change all `.progress-bar`.

Comment: Because `$(this)` doesn't refer to `$(".progress-bar")`

Comment: how to solve that, cause. if i used `$(".progress-bar").data('width') + '%'` it's will changed all of `.progress-bar`. thanks Tushar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're dealing with a scoping issue. The [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method only scopes `this` inside its `complete` callback. Otherwise, it's probably scoping it to the caller.

To solve this, cache your selection in a variable and use it throughout the rest of your code. Besides always maintaining the correct scope, this is technically faster since it doesn't need to re-wrap `this` in a jQuery object.

```
var progressBar = $(".progress-bar");
progressBar.animate({
  width: progressBar.data('width') + '%'
}, 2500);
```

If you're dealing with multiple progress bars, you can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over them and apply the animation to each element while they're still in scope.

```js
$(".progress-bar").each(function(i, item) {
  var progressBar = $(item); // $(this) would work too
  progressBar.animate({
    width: progressBar.data('width') + '%'
  }, 2500);
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="alert alert-success">
  <div class="skill-name">ON PROGRESS 357/487</div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" data-width="70">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thanks. but if i have some class of `progress-bar` , how do that ? how to using `this` for specific class of `.progress-bar` ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `each()`. Have a look.